# Text editor in Windows with real time update?

Tags: text, text-editor

What's a good text editor in Windows that automatically updates the view whenever the opened file has been modified by another process? I need this to watch the output of my program.

Comment: This belongs on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), but as a quick answer, [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/) supports this feature. There's more advanced text editors these days, but it's a very fast editor.

Comment: See my latest answer : Tail for Windows. :-)

Answer (score 7):

If you like using a mouse, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) is great

If you're happier with the keyboard, for me, it has to be [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).  Here's the [download](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) for Windows.

To use the feature in Emacs, add the following to your .emacs:

```
(global-auto-revert-mode t)
```

There are lots of people at work who like Textpad but I don't understand why, it doesn't even have column editing.

Comment: For TRAMP/ssh integration and better experience I recommend `emacs-w32` from Cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ has this feature.

If you want to reload automatically, go to *Settings / Preferences*, then the *MISC* tab and uncheck *Update silently* under *File Status Auto-detection*.

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't update text file automatically. I have to focus-out focus-in notepad++ to update text file. I'm searching for editor that updates fully automatically!

Answer (score 3):

What I use is [snaketail](http://snakenest.com/snaketail/). It can update in real time several files, even without the focus.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Notepad2. It refresh the content automatically without focus switching. You just need to go to menu 'Settings' and set 'File Change Notification...' option, and then save your settings. But keep in mind, refresh has a delay about 2-3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Editplus is great.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really answer your question, but it sounds like what you really want is some kind of console view, not a file. Would it be possible to pipe your program's output into an output stream that's visible in a console instead? Those are designed to show new lines as they arrive, automatically scroll, etc.

Answer (score 0):

See the Viewer (F3 option) in FAR file manager, when End button is pressed, it updates and scrolls text automatically

Answer (score 0):

Use [Tail For Windows](http://tailforwin32.sourceforge.net/).

Tail doesn't need to have focus on.

I've got it from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/106073/text-log-editor-with-auto-refresh-support?newreg=7987e59e58f34002bf9376be288af7d0) answer.

Comment: But SnakeTail is Better ! http://snakenest.com/snaketail/ 

I've got Pc Game that takes full screen (Medieval 2:TW), Tail for Windows on second screen is unable to refresh this game's log file. 
But SnakeTaile works very well.