# Disable auto-scrolling in command window

Tags: matlab, scroll

A lot of the code that I write in Matlab has a very verbose output. As the program runs, information is printed to the command window, and with each new line, the window automatically scrolls to the bottom. This becomes a problem when I want to read some of the output more closely or scroll up to look at older output. I can scroll up, but only until a new line is printed, which is often less than a second.

Does anyone know if it is possible to turn off this automatic scrolling in the Matlab window? I work in a number of different Matlab versions, depending on the machine, and this happens with all of them. The answer to this might be "No", but I swear I remember having this functionality at one point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this workaround useful.

First **launch matlab using the command line** `matlab -logfile 'myLog.txt'` (the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html?searchHighlight=matlab+logfile) says it "starts MATLAB and makes a copy of any output to the Command Window in filename. This includes all crash reports.")

Then **open your .txt file using a text editor supporting automatic refresh of content** (see picture). On OSX I use TextWrangler (freely available at [www](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)) but others have been reported to have this feature (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/106073/text-log-editor-with-auto-refresh-support) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319904/text-editor-in-windows-with-real-time-update)).

**Results**: output displays (fprintf, disp, but not the commands per se) are printed both on the Matlab console and the text editor (file is refreshed with a little lag time, below half a second I would say with my configuration). And there is **no automatic scrolling**. Such procedure does not seem to impact the overall performance of the script (although it may deserve some testing).

[image]

Comment: This definitely seems to work, so marking as correct. Know of any text editors with auto-refresh that come standard with Red Hat?

Comment: nope sorry. probably an answer [here on (SO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592596/can-anyone-recommend-a-linux-utility-to-monitor-logs-in-realtime) for file monitoring in linux.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `more` function: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/more.html

`more on`

Then run your program. Press spacebar when you wish to see more of the output.

`more off` will turn it off.

Comment: The problem with `more` is that it doesn't just stop the display, it pauses the entire program. I want the program to continue unaided. It can continue to print everything, so long as the window doesn't scroll automatically.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it :\. There certainly wasn't in 2003: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/57691

Comment: @Dan455 when more is not sufficient, please see my answer