# Stop Matlab Command History From Jumping

Tags: matlab

Often I will want to repeat several Matlab commands from previous work, but not necessarily all at once. I can easily find these commands in the command history window and copy them across to the command window, but as soon as I execute these commands the command history window jumps down to the most recently executed commands, meaning that I have to scroll back up to find the section I was in for the remaining commands. Can I stop this jump from happening?

Comment: `Often I will want to repeat several Matlab commands from previous work,` then make a script and save it in a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable auto-scrolling in command window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865234/disable-auto-scrolling-in-command-window)

Comment: @NKN, I don't mean the same lines every time though!

Comment: @GameOfThrows, it's not the command window that's the problem, but the command history

Comment: it seems like a simple enough problem, but doesn't seem to have an obvious fix that I can find

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, you can type the first few letters of the command you want then hit the up arrow to find only the commands that match what you've written. This should save you some scrolling....

Comment: how's this? http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16074-is-it-possible-to-make-command-window-scroll-bar-being-in-position-of-it-self-even-by-runnig-a-m-fi